# Shuffle and separate similar strings

Tags: php, sorting

I would like to shuffle emails by domains, making them as far as possible from each other. Example:

Array before:

> email@hotmail.com, email2@hotmail.com, email3@hotmail.com,
>   email@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com, email3@gmail.com, email@yahoo.com,
>   email2@yahoo.com

It would become something like:

Array after:

> email@hotmail.com, email@gmail.com, email@yahoo.com,
>   email2@hotmail.com, email2@gmail.com, email2@yahoo.com,
>   email3@hotmail.com, email3@gmail.com

How can I do it with an Array? If there is any example with PHP it would be great.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: This might help get you started: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$emails = array(
    'mail1@gmail.com',
    'mail2@gmail.com',
    'mail3@gmail.com',
    'mail4@gmail.com',
    'mail5@gmail.com',

    'mail1@yahoo.com',
    'mail2@yahoo.com',
    'mail3@yahoo.com',
    'mail4@yahoo.com',
    'mail5@yahoo.com',

    'mail1@aol.com',
    'mail2@aol.com',
    'mail3@aol.com',
    'mail4@aol.com',
    'mail5@aol.com',

    'mail1@others.com',
    'mail2@others.com',
    'mail3@others.com',
    'mail4@others.com',
    'mail5@others.com',

);

$organized_emails = array();
$needle_key = 0;
$needle_search = array('gmail', 'yahoo', 'aol', 'others');

while(true) {
    $current_value = array_shift($emails);
    if(strpos($current_value, $needle_search[$needle_key]) !== false) {
        $organized_emails[] = $current_value;
        $needle_key++;
        if($needle_key > 3) {
            $needle_key = 0;
        }
    } else {
        array_push($emails, $current_value);
    }

    if(empty($emails)) {
        break;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($organized_emails);
echo '</pre>';
```

Sorry, I just found what I need at [PHP Arrays - Sort by Email Address Domain (alternate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975943/php-arrays-sort-by-email-address-domain-alternate)